# Web API Login with Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Web API and the documentation states I need to save an Auth Token to a cookie then pass it back for API requests. I can get the Auth Token without a problem. My question is what is the best way to save the cookie and send it back in the request.

I create a cookie in the RequestMessage, but I cannot find a way to send it back when making a request against the API. How do I preserve the state of the Login/cookie.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

### Update

I am now able to obtain the cookie from the response. I am using this tutorial. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies Let me point out if you want to use this tutorial make sure you update the Web API 4's code base. In the below method i am trying to simply, Login and Logout. However, I am receiving an Error Code 500.

```
 public HttpWebResponse InitializeWebRequest()
        {
            //HttpResponseMessage logoutMessage = await Logout("bla");
            string responseData = string.Empty;
            string url = GetServerEndPoint();
            string authToken = string.Empty;
            string loginInstance = "https://example.com";

            // Create request.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginInstance);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            IList<string> authHeader = responseData.Split('{', '}').ToList();
            authToken = authHeader[2].Substring(13, 25);
            string sessionId = response.Headers.Get(8);
            var nv = new NameValueCollection();
            nv["sid"] = sessionId;
            nv["token"] = authToken;
            CookieHeaderValue cookieVal = new CookieHeaderValue("session", nv);

            // Log out
            string loginInstance2  = "https://example.com";

            HttpWebRequest request2 =             (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginInstance2);
            request2.Method = "POST";
            request2.ContentType = "application/json";
            request2.Headers.Add(nv);

            HttpWebResponse response2 =           (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## WOW WHAT A PAIN!

I have no idea why this took me so long to figure out, but after hours and hours and DAYs, of trying to get this stupid auth to work I finally figured it out. Here is the code.

One weird thing is I had to create the header format for the cookie. Which by definition isn't a true cookie, it is a damn header value. I had to create the header title, because when I extracted the JSON object from the file and converted it to string I was unable to keep the format in tact from the file.

```
public HttpWebResponse InitiliazeWebRequest()
        {
            string responseData = string.Empty;
            string loginInstance = "url + logincreds";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginInstance);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var toke = response.Headers.Get("authToken");
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseData);
                _authToken = (string)o["response"]["authToken"].ToString();

                return response;
            }
            return response;
        }

  public HttpWebResponse LogOut()
        {
            string responseData = string.Empty;
            string loginInstance = "https://www.example.com/logout";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginInstance);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie: authToken=" + _authToken);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return response;
            }
            return response;
        }
```